# Android - Rich graphics and animations

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, 3d

So far i came through simple applications/games development, i just started seeing what is openGL ES 1/2. What i would like to know is to write games/apps with rich graphics(3d) and animations, what is the starting point of learning? and is there any other tool/IDE to develop such apps/games.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything programming wise is done with existing eclipse and android SDK. For asset creation you need to pick your own 3D modelling package (e.g. blender, 3ds max, maya) and image editor (photoshop, gimp, or even ms paint) for making textures, sprites etc. You'll also need to write an (in-app) parser for whatever 3d model format you choose to save your models as. Android does however have various methods for loading in images

Alternatively, there are some game engines out there for android that you can pick up off the shelf if you don't want to write your own from scratch. [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/unity/) is the only one I can think of right now, but I know there are others as well

Comment: Thanks much!! as beginner i wasnt aware of 3d game engines.and i hope unity3d is free?

Comment: Not used unity3d myself. Just looking at the http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses license page, it has at least a free trial for android. If you go onto the ios page http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/ios you can see it actually lays out how much it costs for publishing on apple ios, but on the equivelant android page it is more vague / doesn't give an exact price. http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/android

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple application for developing graphics and gaming purpose.

1. [3d Game Tutorial - part I](http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series-part-i,770.html)
2. [3d Game Tutorial - part II](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-ii,328.html)

There are lot of application examples available. Please, refer above links.